# How do I make it so that a function is executed only for whatever element I click?

Tags: html, onclick, this, addeventlistener

Ex. Here's an HTML code that displays four images. I'm trying to make it so that whatever image I click, that image gets deleted. Right now with the current code below, only the first image can be deleted upon clicking but not the other ones. I have a gut feeling it has something to do with "this" but apparently I'm doing it wrong here.

```html
   <html>
        <body>
            <div>
                <img id="images" src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/63200502-9bd3-4132-aab8-0e5141db83f5/dbb8tkh-36d702cf-a4a6-45dc-8155-2c55c798e919.jpg/v1/fill/w_916,h_872,q_70,strp/i_got_you_by_cysys8993_dbb8tkh-pre.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3siaGVpZ2h0IjoiPD0xMDI0IiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvNjMyMDA1MDItOWJkMy00MTMyLWFhYjgtMGU1MTQxZGI4M2Y1XC9kYmI4dGtoLTM2ZDcwMmNmLWE0YTYtNDVkYy04MTU1LTJjNTVjNzk4ZTkxOS5qcGciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9MTA3NiJ9XV0sImF1ZCI6WyJ1cm46c2VydmljZTppbWFnZS5vcGVyYXRpb25zIl19.BdzRsmxcfX-QreYXtrBtnPqiXpMiQGp-hlW24z1IDeA" />
                <img id="images" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/44/Red_Dead_Redemption_II.jpg" />
                <img id="images" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/littlewitch/images/1/10/Little_Witch_Academia_TV_official_poster.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170206033308" />
                <img id="images"   src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/fbb1974c1ebbb6bf4c4beae0bb3d9cb93901953c/10_7_2380_1428/master/2380.jpg?width=620&quality=85&auto=format&fit=max&s=1d89b4c566de6bbc7ab42af5588dcf7c" />
            </div>

            <script language="javascript">
             let a = document.getElementById("images");
                let imgray = document.querySelectorAll('img');
                let x;
                for (x of imgray){
                 a.addEventListener('click', removeImage);
                }
        
             function removeImage() {
                    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And btw, the first image is my own illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `for`, you call addEventListener to `a` rather than `x`.

```
for (x of imgray){
    // a.addEventListener('click', removeImage);
    x.addEventListener('click', removeImage);
}
```

That's why good variable names are useful :)